# i want to write a function distance(x, y) that takes two vectors as its input and outputs the distance between them

Tags: python

to calculate the distance between (0,0) and (1,1) i write this code but it has been generating errors

```
def distance(x,y):
    for i,j in x,y:
        x=(x[i],x[j])
        y=(y[i],y[j])
        a=x[i], b=x[j], c=y[i], d=y[j]
        new_distance =((d-b)**2+(c-a)**2)**(1/2)
        return new_distance

print(distance((0,0),(1,1)))
```

and error is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-419-502ff9d672fc> in <module>
      7         return new_distance
      8 
----> 9 print(distance((0,0),(1,1)))

<ipython-input-419-502ff9d672fc> in distance(x, y)
      3         x=(x[i],x[j])
      4         y=(y[i],y[j])
----> 5         a=x[i], b=x[j], c=y[i], d=y[j]
      6         new_distance =((d-b)**2+(c-a)**2)**(1/2)
      7         return new_distance

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

can you help

Comment: easier way would to use numpy.linalg.norm(a-b) to calculate the distance.

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple

```
def dist(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    return ((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2)**0.5

def dist_vec(p1,p2):
    return dist(p1[0],p1[1],p2[0],p2[1])

print(dist_vec((0,0),(1,1)))
```